# CMakeLists won't include Boost headers

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, cmake

I'm trying to compile a CPP library which requires Boost. I'm under Ubuntu.

In one of my file I include on of the boost headers

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
```

This is the `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)


find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system serialization REQUIRED)

set(CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR include)

include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}   
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/boost #this is not the boost I'm talking about
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/timers_rtpreempt
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/timers_unix
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/timers_xeno
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/unix

)
LINK_DIRECTORIES($ENV{HOME}/Projects/canmaster/bin)

set(CAN_FESTIVAL_CPP drivers/unix/unix.c
    drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.c
)

add_library(canfestival ${CAN_FESTIVAL_CPP})
```

When I try to compile `cd buil && cmake .. && make VERBOSE=1`, it returns the following error:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster -B/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake/CMakeFiles /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake'
make -f CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake'
cd /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake/CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake/CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target canfestival
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake'
make -f CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake/CMakeFiles 1
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o
/usr/bin/gcc   -I/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include -I/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/boost -I/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/timers_rtpreempt -I/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/timers_unix -I/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/timers_xeno -I/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/unix    -o CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o   -c /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/drivers/unix/unix.c
In file included from /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/can.h:28:0,
                 from /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/canDispatch.h:23,
                 from /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/drivers/unix/unix.c:36:
/usr/include/boost/function.hpp:13:57: fatal error: functional: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems that the boost path is not included. And it is the same if I try to replace `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}` with `/usr/include` in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

How can I fix it?

EDIT

This is the result of boost debug:

```
luca@luca-vmware:~/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake$ cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:525 ] Boost not in cache
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:528 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:530 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:532 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:534 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:536 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:538 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:606 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:608 ]   BOOST_ROOT = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:610 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:612 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:614 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:667 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:669 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/boost/include;/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:671 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost-1_47_0;boost_1_47_0;boost-1_47;boost_1_47;boost-1_46_1;boost_1_46_1;boost-1_46_0;boost_1_46_0;boost-1_46;boost_1_46;boost-1_45_0;boost_1_45_0;boost-1_45;boost_1_45;boost-1_44_0;boost_1_44_0;boost-1_44;boost_1_44;boost-1_43_0;boost_1_43_0;boost-1_43;boost_1_43;boost-1_42_0;boost_1_42_0;boost-1_42;boost_1_42;boost-1_41_0;boost_1_41_0;boost-1_41;boost_1_41;boost-1_40_0;boost_1_40_0;boost-1_40;boost_1_40;boost-1_39_0;boost_1_39_0;boost-1_39;boost_1_39;boost-1_38_0;boost_1_38_0;boost-1_38;boost_1_38;boost-1_37_0;boost_1_37_0;boost-1_37;boost_1_37;boost-1_36_1;boost_1_36_1;boost-1_36_0;boost_1_36_0;boost-1_36;boost_1_36;boost-1_35_1;boost_1_35_1;boost-1_35_0;boost_1_35_0;boost-1_35;boost_1_35;boost-1_34_1;boost_1_34_1;boost-1_34_0;boost_1_34_0;boost-1_34;boost_1_34;boost-1_33_1;boost_1_33_1;boost-1_33_0;boost_1_33_0;boost-1_33;boost_1_33
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:696 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:715 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.46.1
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:808 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc46
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:818 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:861 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:863 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:906 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/include/lib;/usr/include/../lib;/usr/include/stage/lib;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/boost/boost_1_46_1/lib;/boost/boost_1_46/lib;/boost/lib;/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-1_46_1;boost_filesystem-gcc46-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_46_1;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_filesystem-gcc46-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc46-mt-1_46_1;boost_system-gcc46-mt;boost_system-mt-1_46_1;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-gcc46-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_system-gcc46-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_serialization-gcc46-mt-1_46_1;boost_serialization-gcc46-mt;boost_serialization-mt-1_46_1;boost_serialization-mt;boost_serialization
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_serialization-gcc46-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_serialization-gcc46-mt-d;boost_serialization-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_serialization-mt-d;boost_serialization-mt;boost_serialization
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1119 ] Boost_FOUND = TRUE
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
--   serialization
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake
luca@luca-vmware:~/ArmIkarus/canmaster/build_cmake$ make
Scanning dependencies of target canfestival
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o
In file included from /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/can.h:28:0,
                 from /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/include/canDispatch.h:23,
                 from /home/luca/ArmIkarus/canmaster/drivers/unix/unix.c:36:
/usr/include/boost/function.hpp:13:57: fatal error: functional: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: It looks like the C++ standard library is not in the include path. To make a project use C++ regardless of the file extension use `project(FOOBAR CXX)`.

Comment: @pmr thanks, that solved the problem! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I created a new question in which I better explain the new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917798/error-in-moving-from-makefile-to-cmake

Comment: I'm lost. Is the answer still the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, adjusting settings and version as needed:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package( Boost 1.52.0 COMPONENTS date_time filesystem system )
if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries(canfestival ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Edit:

I overlooked it earlier but given that your source files are .c instead of .cpp cmake is (correctly) compiling your library as C objects as you can see in your debug output:

```
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o
```

Compare to:

```
[  2%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/smolder.dir/os/linux/main.cpp.o
```

Boost is a C++ library so the error you are seeing is because it doesn't understand the function.hpp header file structure, specifically the first include:

fatal error: functional: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

```
#include<functional>
```

is the first line in [function.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/function.hpp)

Edited for future reference:
My initial suggestion was to change the source files to .cpp and but this can be forced via:

```
project(FOOBAR CXX)
```

Comment: Thanks, however it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Where are your boost headers actually installed? For me they are in: /usr/local/include/boost

Comment: Having located the actual directory, re run cmake with as follows to find the search paths it is using via FindBoost.cmake: cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON

You want to look for something like:  [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:906 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/local/include/lib;.....

Comment: My Boost is located in `/usr/include/boost`

Comment: @I did what you said in the second comment. It returns ` [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:906 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/include/lib ...` What I have to do now?

Comment: My apologies I grabbed the wrong console log line, you want to check: _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/boost/include;/boost;/sw/local/include

Depending on what you see there you can either manually set Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS or you could create a symlink in the search path to your actual boost location.

Comment: This seems to be more Windows path. I'm under Ubuntu. This is the result `boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/boost/include;/boost;/sw/local/include`. I tried to put `\usr\include` in the `include_directories` but that didn't wiork

Comment: If you post all of the debug output regarding boost to your question, I think I can edit my answer and give you a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. It resolve the issue I reported but it gives me another error. Probably it worth to say that I'm trying to move from Makefile to CMakeLists and that all the code compiled with Makefile. Without modifying the file extensions.

Comment: Maybe it can be usefull to see the Makefile: https://bitbucket.org/skratochwil/canfestival-3-fm3/src/7758d60e9260/drivers/timers_xeno/Makefile.in

Comment: I also had to add project(FOOBAR CXX)!

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo. It's `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})`, not `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})`. Plural.

Answer (score 1):

Your files have an extension that is recognized by CMake as `C` source code. You need to force CMake to compile your project as a C++ project by using

```
project(FOO CXX)
```

In general you should have a more cplusplus-y extension for your files like: `cc` or `cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem can be fixed as described by pmr:

> Your files have an extension that is recognized by CMake as C source code. You need to force CMake to compile your project as a C++ project by using

`project(FOO CXX)`

> In general you should have a more cplusplus-y extension for your files like: cc or cpp.