# Error in migrating from Makefile to CMake

Tags: boost, cmake

I have a library which compile without error using Makefile.
Now I want to switch to CMake but it doesn't work.

The sources and the Makefiles are [here](https://bitbucket.org/skratochwil/canfestival-3-fm3/src/7758d60e9260/drivers?at=default).
From all the folders I have kept the followin: `can_socket, can_virtual, timers_xeno,  timers_rtpreempt,  timers_unix, unix`.

This is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
project(ikarus_arm_common C CXX)


#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)


find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system serialization REQUIRED)

set(CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR include)

include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}  
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR} 
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/boost
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/timers_rtpreempt
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/timers_unix
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/timers_xeno
    ${CAN_MASTER_INCLUDE_DIR}/unix
    /usr/xenomai/include

)

set(CAN_FESTIVAL_CPP drivers/unix/unix.c
    drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.c
    drivers/can_socket/can_socket.c
)

add_library(canfestival ${CAN_FESTIVAL_CPP})
```

EDIT:

When I try to compile it returns the following error:

```
> $ make 
> [  9%] Building C object
> CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o 
> In file included from
> /home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/include/can.h:28:0,
>     from /home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/include/canDispatch.h:23,
>     from /home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/drivers/unix/unix.c:36:
> /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:13:57: fatal error: functional: No
> such file or directory compilation terminated. make[2]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o] Error 1 make[1]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I suppose that one of the problems is due to the fact that some files have the extension `.c` but requires boost. If i modify the extension of the files `unix.cpp and can_socket.cpp` compile, while `timers_xeno` returns an error:

```
luca@luca-vmware:~/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/build$ make
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/unix/unix.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.o
/home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.cpp: In function ‘void CreateReceiveTask(CAN_PORT, pthread_t*, void (*)(void*))’:
/home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.cpp:250:75: error: cannot convert ‘pthread_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ to ‘RT_TASK* {aka rt_task_placeholder*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int rt_task_create(RT_TASK*, const char*, int, int, int)’
/home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.cpp:256:70: error: cannot convert ‘pthread_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ to ‘RT_TASK* {aka rt_task_placeholder*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int rt_task_start(RT_TASK*, void (*)(void*), void*)’
/home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.cpp: In function ‘void WaitReceiveTaskEnd(pthread_t*)’:
/home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.cpp:270:38: error: cannot convert ‘pthread_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ to ‘RT_TASK* {aka rt_task_placeholder*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int rt_task_join(RT_TASK*)’
/home/luca/ArmIkarus/ikarus_arm_stack/ikarus_arm_common/drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.cpp:273:36: error: cannot convert ‘pthread_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ to ‘RT_TASK* {aka rt_task_placeholder*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int rt_task_delete(RT_TASK*)’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/drivers/timers_xeno/timers_xeno.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/canfestival.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If code author compiled these files as C, you shouldn't compile them as C++. What's the problem when these files have `.c` extension?

Comment: @arrowdodger please see the updated question. I inserted the info you required. thanks

Comment: It's the problem with the author's code. Ask him why he's including C++ headers in C source.

Comment: @arrowdodger yes but the question is, why it compiles with Makefile and not with CMake??

Comment: No idea. You can try comparing command lines used to compile that source. For CMake use `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: @arrowdodger This is the verbose of make on unix.c. It seeems I'm already including all the headers. What about D flags? How can I use them with CMake? make[2]: Entering directory `/home/arm/Projects/canmaster/drivers/unix'
ccache g++ -O2 -g -I/usr/xenomai/include -DUSE_XENO -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -Wall -pipe -D__XENO__  -I../../include -I../../include/unix -I../../include/timers_xeno -o ../../build/unix.o -c unix.c
Building [libcanfestival_unix.a]
ar rc ../../bin/libcanfestival_unix.a ../../build/unix.o ../../build/timers_xeno.o
ranlib ../../bin/libcanfestival_unix.a

Comment: I haven't used boost with cmake before, but usually you can expect that a good c++ header-only library can be consumed in cmake by using target_link_libraries instead of include_directories.